# Regex to match some pattern with line break

Tags: java, regex

I want to write regEx to match following pattern:

```
From: ***********************
Sent: ***********************
To: ***********************
Subject: *******************
```

I wrote regEx as

```
.*From:.+(\n)Sent:.+(\n)To:.+(\n)Subject:.+(\n).*
```

But this is not working. Kindly help me as I am new to regEx.

Comment: Too many duplicates of this question to list :/

Comment: It might not be working because the newline sequence can be `\r\n`, or `\r`, or `\n`. In PCRE regex, use `\R`. Also, after `Subject:...` there is no newline. Here is one that works: [`.*From:.+\R+Sent:.+\R+To:.+\R+Subject:.+`](https://regex101.com/r/zT1zY7/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew shouldn't this work as well? `(?s).*From:.+Sent:.+To:.+Subject:.+`

Comment: Yeah. Went through various post but wasn't able to get the solution.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: There are a lot of variations that will work the same. Literal newlines, character class, `\R`, etc. The `(?s)` DOTALL modifier should be avoided if you need to match specific lines only.

Comment: @slayer: If you have just `\n` as newline separators, just use your own regex, only remove the final `(\n).*`. [It also works](https://regex101.com/r/zT1zY7/3). And I'd remove the `(` and `)` around `\n`, those capturing groups make no sense.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sure.. an evil copy paste situation :) thanks

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Tried  .*From:.+\R+Sent:.+\R+To:.+\R+Subject:.+ but not working. unsupported escape sequence for "\R"

Comment: @slayer: What programming language is it? Or tool? Regex flavor is important. As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: @slayer: If you have linebreaks `\r\n`, replace all `\n` with `\r?\n`. Use `From:.+\r?\nSent:.+\r?\nTo:.+\r?\nSubject:.+` and search for a *partial* match.

Comment: Why do you need to capture the line breaks?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: Your solution "From:.+\r?\nSent:.+\r?\nTo:.+\r?\nSubject:.+" worked. Thanks a lot. I appreciate your effort. I'm using Java RegEx flavour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex does not work because of two possible reasons:

- The newline sequence can be `\r\n`, or `\r`, or `\n` (or even more, `\u000B`, `\u000C`, `\u0085`, `\u2028` or `\u2029`), but you only coded in the LF. Adding an optional CR (carriage return, `\r`) can help.
- Also, after `Subject:...`, there is no newline, so you need to remove it.
- In Java 8+, there is a [special line break shorthand class, `\R`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), that you may use to match any line break sequence.

You can use

```
From:.+\r?\nSent:.+\r?\nTo:.+\r?\nSubject:.+
From:.+\RSent:.+\RTo:.+\RSubject:.+
```

Search for a partial match with `Matcher#find()`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zT1zY7/5)

And the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ojj89m):

```
String p = "From:.+\r?\nSent:.+\r?\nTo:.+\r?\nSubject:.+"; 
// String p = "From:.+\\RSent:.+\\RTo:.+\\RSubject:.+";  // Java 8+ compliant
String s = "Some text before.....\r\nFrom: ***********************\r\nSent: ***********************\r\nTo: ***********************\r\nSubject: *******************"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like this;

`From:.+\nSent:.+\nTo:.+\nSubject:.+`

The regex you have given might fail since you do not need the starting `.*` since you want to capture from "From:" part.

If you only wish to capture the text;

`From:(.+)\nSent:(.+)\nTo:(.+)\nSubject:(.+)`

where

$1 -> From text

$2 -> Sent text

$3 -> To text

$4 -> Subject text

You can use any regex utilizing functions from whichever language using to get these captured groups

Comment: `.*` can very well sit on the beginning of the line as it matches any character **zero** or more times. It fails as it eats up everything and should be lazy in this case (`.*?`) or ommited at all as not needed.

Comment: With `.*` at the beginning, he might capture unwanted text such as -> `asdfFrom: *****` will be captured with silly `asdf`

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved as follows:

```
^From:\s.(?P<from>.+)\R   # look for "From:" at the beginning of the line/string,
                           # followed by a capturing group and `R`
Sent:\s(?P<sent>.+)\R      # same as above  
To:\s(?P<to>.+)\R
Subject:\s(?P<subject>.+)
```

The code works if you use `PCRE` (i.e. `PHP`, etc.).
See [a demo here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xM1gD6/3) (with `m` and `x` flags).

Answer (score 0):

IMO you can use a regex like this:

```
/^(?=From: ).*([\r\n]|\r\n)(?=Sent: ).*([\r\n]|\r\n)(?=To: ).*([\r\n]|\r\n)(?=Subject: ).*$/gm
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/hG4rB1/1)